# Is the sequence of numbers generated by the range() function a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, range

On an online course, the teacher says that range() produces a tuple, adding that this is the reason why we have to convert it into a list (thanks to the list() function) if we want to modify it.

Is this statement true ?

Because in the official documentation, they dont talk about tuple at all in the range() section : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function

Comment: The statement is not true. The range function returns a range type. "In many ways the object returned by range() behaves as if it is a list, but in fact it isn’t. It is an object which returns the successive items of the desired sequence when you iterate over it, but it doesn’t really make the list, thus saving space."

Comment: Just for completeness: in (outdated) Python 2 `range()` returned a `list` (no `tuple`).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I imagine the teacher wanted to say (as we can read in the answer of this question similar to mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43776128/what-is-the-return-value-of-the-range-function-in-python ) that range() returns an "immutable sequence type" and that's why he used improperly the word tuple, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with python3, `range` returns a `range` object which is a [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) which, among other things, can be iterated to create a list out of it.

[Relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) about the `range` type.

Before that, it used to return a list, like Klaus commented. ([docs](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/functions.html#range))